# Mage::init('default') causing error in Module

Tags: php, magento

I have test php script running outside of Magento that will add an item to the cart.  Works great.  This code was found here and used by many people in quite a few posts.  When I place this code into an existing module, the item is not added, from a fresh session.  If I go to the store and add a regular product (have an item in my cart) the module will add the item properly.  I Know the code to add the item works.  The problem I have is with creating the FIRST instance of a cart.

This code works just fine if already have a normal magento product in my cart:

```
            // this section of code only works if the customer already has a cart item added (cart established)
            // for some reason this script fails when no cart exists

            $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session'); 
            // Get cart instance
            $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart'); 
            $cart->init();
            $productId=971;             
            $productInstance = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
            $param = array(
                'product' => $productId,
                'qty' => $rfqdata['option_quantity'],
                'options' => array(
                    27 => $rfqdata['option_layers'],        // Layers
                    26 => $rfqdata['option_thickness'],     // Thickness
                    25 => $rfqdata['option_length'],        // Length
                    24 => $rfqdata['option_width'],         // Width
                    23 => $rfqdata['option_color'],         // Color
                    22 => $rfqdata['option_finish'],        // Finish
                    29 => $rfqdata['option_rush'],          // Rush
                    30 => 'tbd'                             // RFQ Number
                )
            );
            $request = new Varien_Object();
            $request->setData($param);
            $cart->addProduct($productInstance, $param);
            $session->setCartWasUpdated(true);
            $cart->save();
```

This somehow causes an error, and the module addtocart action is not completed.  I cannot find any useful error messages. I have searched 100s of pages on stack, google, and I can find nothing to resolve this issue.   Obviously my module is worthless if it doesn't work from page load 1.

I tried to post this before and got no response.  I really need some help.  If you cannot answer, can you tell me where I can find paid Magento support?

Comment: If it is in a module (which is loaded by Magento), why are you again loading up magento using `Mage::init()` ???

Comment: I'm not, those are the lines I have to remove to make it work in the Module.  I am assuming outside of magento these lines initialize and start the session.  THe problem is,  without an item already in the cart,  the "session" is not started/setup yet when module tries to add?  I dunno, that is why I am drowning and looking for lifesaver here....

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with the code? And ammend your question with the code you are adding to your module... And the module should be here as well...

Comment: This is a tweak of FME QuickRFQ which creates an RFQ and adds an purchaseable item to the cart.  3 Observers update the price of the item based on custom options from the RFQ page.  This all works.  I will try amending the code now.  Thank you

Comment: able to see the exception errors now when it fails, that's very helpful...its failing on some SQL related to sales_flat_quote_item   -  which again back to the original issue,  within the module on page load 1,  no valid cart session is there to add too...

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution, it was very hard to find too....

```
if(empty($quote)){
    $checkout = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
    $quote = $checkout->getQuote();
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
    if($session->isLoggedIn()) {
        // look up customer
        $customerSession = $session->getCustomer();
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerSession->getId());
        $quote->assignCustomer($customer);
        $quote->setIsMultiShipping(false);
    }
    $quote->save();
}
```